# how to get the user editable table value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all values in my table into one object. But my table has both editable and readonly `<td>`. if I enter any data in editable `<td>`, I am not able to get the same with below code. Please someone help me to get the required result.

```js
var itemtbl = $('table#itemtable tr').map(function() {
     return $(this).find('td').map(function() {
      if($(this).find('input[type="text"],textarea').length) {
   alert("i am in text area");
      return $(this).val();
    } else {
     alert("i am in readonly");
     return $(this).text();
    }
      }).get();
     }).get();
```

```js
//table will be loaded dynamically as below and create both editable and non-ediatble<td>
$.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
  var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
  rowNew.children().eq(0).append(i);                       rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['itemcode']);                  rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['itemname']);                  rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['receivedqty']);                rowNew.children().eq(4).html('<input type="text"  id="inspdate"/>');
  rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<input type="text"  id="accqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>');
  rowNew.children().eq(6).html('<input type="text"  id="rejqty" class="reject"/>');
 rowNew.children().eq(7).html('<input type="text"  id="rema"/>');
 rowNew.appendTo($tbody);
 i++;
});
```

Comment: check if it has input and if there is, get the input value.

Comment: Please check my updated code. used val() ; but no luck

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table#itemtable").find("tr").each(function(){
   // get each tr
   $(this).find("td").each(function{
   // handle each td in current tr
         if (!$(this).find("input"))
         {
            // no input elements here
            var data = $(this).text()
             // now data contains cell text
         }
   })
})
```

Your code should be changed to:

```
 var itemtbl = $('table#itemtable tr').map(function() {
    return $(this).find('td').map(function() {
        if($(this).find('input[type="text"],textarea').length) {
        alert("i am in text area");

        // $(this) will point to current <td> element, not to input
          //            return $(this).val();
         return $(this).find('input[type="text"],textarea').val();
        // and this is correct context

      } else {
          alert("i am in readonly");
          return $(this).text();
      }
        }).get();
    }).get();
```

Comment: Thanks. Please check my updated code. Used val() to get the user data. but not able to get any!

Comment: offcourse. You use $(this), when still in "td" context and truing to get val() from td element